# Laravel 4 - Javascript get response header

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

How do i detect laravel response header?

My javascript to check is but it doesn't work

```
if (xhr.getResponseHeader('location'))
{
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('location'));
}
```

and this is my server code to redirect

```
Redirect::guest('landing');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript to get the headers of the current page:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('HEAD', document.location, false);
request.send(null);

console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

Than you can see if there is a laravel header being sent or not

Comment: it doesn't contain any redirect/location header